# Do these series vanish asymptotically?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

Let's consider a monotone increasing sequence $(K_N) \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ with $(K_N) \xrightarrow[N]{} \infty$ and $(K_N) = \mathrm o(N)$ (less increasing than $(N)$).

1. Question: $\sum_{j=K_N + 1}^N 1/j \longrightarrow_N 0\,?$
2. Question: What are necessary conditions for $(a_j) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such 
            that $\sum_{j=K_N + 1}^N|a_j|\longrightarrow_N 0\,?$

To 1. Question: I think it doesn't work, but I'm not sure: I tried to prove this with the Euler's constant $\gamma$ - if $\sum_{j=1}^{K_N}1/j - \text{ln}(K_N) \longrightarrow_N \gamma$ (does the limit depend on the asymptotic behaviour of $(K_N)$ ? ) it shouldn't work in general (e.g. set $(K_N) = (\lfloor N^{1/2}\rfloor)$).

To 2. Question: I could imagine that it works for absolutely summable $(a_j) \in \ell^1.$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $K_N=\lfloor \sqrt N\rfloor$. Then $K_N/N\to0$, and 
$$
\sum_{j=K_N}^N\frac1j\geq\sum_{j=K_N}^N\frac1N=\frac{N-\lfloor \sqrt N\rfloor+1}N\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{}1.
$$

As you say, if $a\in\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, then 
$$
\sum_{j=K_N + 1}^N|a_j|\leq\sum_{j=K_N + 1}^\infty|a_j|\longrightarrow_N 0.
$$
So $a\in\ell^1 (\mathbb N) $ is a sufficient condition. An obvious necessary condition is $a_n\to0$. It might be possible to find a stronger necessary condition, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you. How do I prove your second assertion?

Comment: You mean the inequality? That's just the fact that $a\in\ell^1$.

Comment: No, I meant the second part (the limit), which it's actually obvious, because with $a = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|a_j|$ we get $\sum_{j=K_N + 1}^{\infty}|a_j| = a - \sum_{j=1}^{K_N}|a_j| \rightarrow_N 0.$

Thanks!